# AutocompleteTextview drop down list direction

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have a problem with an Autocompletetextview. If I use an emulator with wvga800 resolution and I have the autocompletetextview on the bottom of the screen, the direction of the drop down list is down, while if I use an emulator with a HVGA resolution the direction is up (the direction I want).

How can I indicate the direction of an autocompletetextview drop down list?

Regards.