# AutoCompleteTextView drop down list showing at the top

Tags: android, android-layout, autocompletetextview

My AutoCompleteTextView drop down list does not always appear beneath the TextView. Sometimes , when there is a long list of results, it appears above the TextView. When that happens, the background that I set using `setDropDownBackgroundResource` is not applied. Does anyone know how to correct this behavior? I need for my background to apply at all time and to keep the list beneath the TextView at all time.

Comment: setDropDownBackgroundResource should always keep the background . Can you post your code

Comment: @Libin My code is an EXACT copy of the sample at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html with the addition of `textview.setDropDownBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_img)`. Nothing more.

Comment: It appears I am not the first to notice this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183112/autocompletetextview-drop-down-list-direction?rq=1

Comment: I think , showing up/down depends on the space available and position of the AutoCompleteTextView

Comment: the problem is that it starts in the up position and then as I type it flips. This is poor user experience. There should be a way to keep it in one location. I know my layout; I should be able to set a flag or such.